# How do I count the number of rows, which have the same values in 1 column

Tags: sql

[image: EMPLOYEE]

This is my table. How do I count the number of `ENAME` which have the same job?

Looking at the table I can see that the answer is 13, but how do I count it?

```
SELECT COUNT(ename)
FROM emp
GROUP by job
```

This SQL statement above is not the code I am looking for :))

---

Comment: Do you want the number of people pr. job, or the number of people who have a job that someone else has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of employees that have the same job.  One method is an aggregation of aggregation approach.  If we count the number of employees per job, then the sum is the number of times this number is greater than 1:

```
select sum(case when cnt > 1 then cnt else 0 end)
from (select emp.job, count(*) as cnt
      from emp
      group by emp.job
     ) j;
```

This can also be written as:

```
select sum(ccnt)
from (select emp.job, count(*) as cnt
      from emp
      group by emp.job
      having count(*) > 1
     ) j;
```

There is a `join` approach.  But perhaps an easier way to think about this is using `exists` rather than `join`:

```
select count(*)
from emp e
where exists (select 1
              from emp e2
              where e2.job = e.job and e2.empno <> e.empno
             );
```

With an index on `emp(job, empno)`, this is probably the fastest method.

Comment: I would adjust the first option so that is uses a HAVING statement in the sub query group by emp.job HAVING COUNT(*) > 1. This removes the need for a case in the main query.